# Rendering Divs in an Index action with bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a Ruby on Rails app with a TradingCard model. I have an index action and corresponding view where I am trying to print out each TradingCard object. Here's basically what I've got in my controller, under my index action:

```
@trading_cards = TradingCard.all
```

Here's my issue: I am using bootstrap to help me out with the basic grid-like approach of the styling, as well as its convenience on small mobile screens. I'm using bootstrap to help with the general layout and flow, but I've constructed my own little trading-card-esque container for each TradingCard object; I wrote it with my own CSS. It has no specified height, so it can be as tall as it needs to be to fit in all of the text specific to that individual object. 
On medium sized screens, I would like for my Index view to simply display three trading cards per row, WHERE EACH ROW ISN'T OBSTRUCTED BY A TRADING CARD FROM THE ROW BELOW IT. This is a problem, because best practice is to simply include the following in your index view, (of course with a _trading_card partial in the view folder):

```
<%= render @trading_cards %>
```

And in my _trading_card partial I have something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<%= trading_card.body %>
</div>
```

The only problem with this approach is that I can't really tell the layout to create a new row every 3 trading cards. Instead, I have to just keep spitting out col-md-4 into one really really long row and as a result, some of the taller trading cards end up squeezing themselves up into the rows above them, and it looks really odd.

Is there a better way to go about this entire approach? Am I missing something? Or is there a way to specify in my controller that I want to load the objects in bundles of 3 so that I can just write an iteration that creates a new row with every time through the loop?

Any help is so much appreciated. Sorry if this question was really long. You guys are always so helpful and I really can't thank you all enough.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!!

Comment: seems like you could use `each_slice` to loop through your objects/items. eg: `@trading_cards.each_slice(3) do |cards|; end` would take 3 objects at a time

Comment: Hey Alfie, I was completely unaware of the existence of each_slice(). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `render @trading_cards` to loop through your `TradingCard`s for you. You could do that yourself in slices of 3 (as @alfie suggested).

```
<% @trading_cards.each_slice(3) do |cards| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% cards.each do |card| %>
      <%= render card %>   <!-- This will render your `_trading_card` partial -->
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea that .each_slice() even existed! I think this solves my problem. Thanks so much for the help, both of you!